# JavaScript master detail panel - how to pass ajax object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting response to a Ajax request with returned object as data with let says 10-15 parameters.

Now I am adding for each item a table row in master page, how can I pass this data for each item when clicked on other side of details function without making another ajax call or adding all param as data-attributes...

This is what's happening on master panel,

```
function addFruitRow(data) {
    $('#fruittable').append(
        '<tr itemId="' + data.FruitID + '" onclick="Load_Fruit_Details($(' + data + ')); class="dRow">' +
            '<td class="dCell" style="width:40px;"><img src="' + data.FruitUrl + '" class="avatar" /></td>' +
            '<td class="dCell" style="vertical-align: top; padding-top:8px;"><span class="fruitItem">' + data.Family + '</span></td>' +
        '</tr>');
}
```

**Edit when using json.stringify**

```
<tr class="dRow" itemid="s-1-4-34-345345345-345345-3651691534-2343" onclick="loadMember1($({" address":null,"bio":null,"clientid":0,"email":"blahblah.one@frutfactory.com","isReady":0,
"mobile":"22222","name":"blah123="" haaaa","phone":"1111","pictureurl":"https:="" 2013.frutfactory.com="" us="" t3="" br="" t302062015111222="" fruits="" fruits.png",
"usersid":"s-1-4-34-345345345-345345-3651691534-2343","username":"blah123.haaaa"}));=""><td class="dCell" style="width:40px;">
<img src="https://2013.frutfactory.cm/us/t3/br/t302062015111222/fruits/fruits.png" class="avatar"></td><td class="dCell" style="vertical-align: top; padding-top:8px;">
<span class="memberItem">blah123 haaaa</span></td></tr>
```

Real data:

```
Address: null
Bio: null
ClientID: 0
Email: "blahblah.one@frutfactory.com"
isReady: 0
Mobile: "22222"
Name: "blah123 haaaa"
Phone: "1111"
PictureUrl: "https://2013.frutfactory.cm/us/t3/br/t302062015111222/fruits/fruits.png"
UserSID: "s-1-4-34-345345345-345345-3651691534-2343"
Username: "blah123.haaaa"
__proto__: Object
```

**Error on click**

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Add the whole object for that row to a `data()` property on the `tr`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you give example please, thank you

Comment: Can you expand your code sample to include the AJAX request and show how you are looping over the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the data to the load function using JSON.stringify (data) and then receive it in the load function using JSON.parse (parameter).

**EXAMPLE**

**EDIT1**

```
function addFruitRow(data) {
 $('#fruittable').append(
'<tr itemId="' + data.FruitID + 
'" onclick=\'Load_Fruit_Details($(' + JSON.stringify (data) + '));\' class="dRow">' +
    '<td class="dCell" style="width:40px;"><img src="' + data.FruitUrl + '" class="avatar" /></td>' +
    '<td class="dCell" style="vertical-align: top; padding-top:8px;"><span class="fruitItem">' + data.Family + '</span></td>' +
'</tr>');
}
```

**EDIT2**

I found that just passing the data in the stringify format, it is being received as an object in the Load functionality. Also I have added an escape to the single quotes as such your function will be inside the onclick event call.

```
function Load_Fruit_Details(param)
{ 
  var data=param;
}
```

Comment: thanks +1, but one of parameter is url and it's not going well with that, also  do i still need to pass it a s a jquery object ? and btw i tried encoding using this encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(object_to_be_serialised)) but then it adds a lot of "%"

Comment: One thing you can do if you are using the `encodeURIComponent`, in the load function you can write `var decode=decodeURIComponent(param);` followed by `var data=JSON.parse(decode);`  and then it should give you the desired result.

Comment: hi, please see edited question i added output to what you suggest to change, there is something wrong with rendered output and i am receiving an error

Comment: Please find above the edited code. Sorry it took a while to reply back.